# How to restrict custom shipping method in checkout by selected address

Tags: magento2

Need to restrict my custom shipping method to not showing on checkout page using http service to check if shipping address is applicable.

That is my code

```
   public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $shippingCost = (float)$this->getConfigData('shipping_cost');

    $method->setPrice($shippingCost);
    $method->setCost($shippingCost);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

I need to check with http service selected shipping address before append method. Can anybody help me how to get current selected shipping method?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I missing the question, below is your method amended to show you the change I would do to implement your need

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

// This is the function to add and within it, you may add an API call to your http service
    if (!$this->myHttpServiceIsNotApplicable()) {
       return false;
    }


    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $shippingCost = (float)$this->getConfigData('shipping_cost');

    $method->setPrice($shippingCost);
    $method->setCost($shippingCost);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my really problem is how to get shipping address selected on checkout page.